# jQuery Dialog Modal (only open one when there is multiple ones on a page)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Ok I am looping through my news postings and each one you can comment on. So I built a dialog modal for each news posting (which I think is silly), but it's the only way I can keep the news_id looping through and passing it into the form action attribute.

Anyway, hopefully that's not such a huge deal, but whenever I click on a comment link (.comment), it opens up ALL of the repeating dialog modals since it's the same class. How do I make it only open up that dialog modal with the same news id as the comment link they are clicking on so I can insert their comment based on the news id?

This is the HTML for my news looping (using CodeIgniter)

```
<div id="news">
    <?php foreach($news_array as $news) { ?>

    <div class="news_box">
        <h3 align="right">Peanut - December 18, 2012</h3>
        <p align="right"><?php if($admin) { echo anchor('admin/news/edit/'.$news->id, 'Edit').' | '.anchor('admin/news/delete/'.$news->id, 'Delete', array('onClick' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post?')")); } ?></p>
        <h2><?php echo $news->title; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo nl2br($news->body); ?></p>
        <p align="right"><?php echo anchor('news/comment/'.$news->id, 'Comment', array('class' => 'comment', 'onclick' => 'return false')); ?></p>

        <div class="comment-form" title="Comment">
            <?php echo form_open('news/comment/'.$news->id, array('class' => 'form')); ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please Leave A Comment</legend>
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="full control-groups">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="form-status"></div>
                            <?php echo form_label('Comment', 'comment'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo form_textarea(array('name' => 'comment', 'id' => $news->id, 'maxlength' => 200, 'placeholder' => 'Please enter 5 - 200 characters.', 'value' => set_value('comment'))); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <? echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>

        <hr color="orange" />
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Then here is my Javascript (only showing the important stuff so it's not all jumbled together):

```
$('.comment-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 380,
    width: 900,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Comment": function() {
            form = $('.form');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                type: (form.attr('method'))
            });
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
$('.comment').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.comment').find('.comment-form').dialog('open');
});
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do it. I'd probably just do it like this. Give each comment form an id e.g. `id="comment-form-0"`, `id="comment-form-1"` etc as you're looping through and creating them in PHP.

Also for each comment element you store an HTML5 data attribute on it e.g. `data-comment-id="0"`, `data-comment-id="1"`.

Then in the JavaScript you'd do something like:

```
$('.comment').click(function() {
    var commentId = $(this).attr('data-comment-id');
    $('#comment-form-' + commentId).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: I can not put a random number on the comment-form boxes because they are dialog boxes and are put on display: none; from having the autoOpen attribute set to false so no PHP will go on them because it's acting as if they aren't there.. I've already tried that many times.

Comment: And plus I would have to create an id dialog modal for each news id and i dont know how much there will be. There could be 2, there could be 10.. or even more.. I'm just gonna make it slide down instead of be a dialog modal.

Comment: @Peanut How about putting up a reduced test case (basic html, js, css) on JSFiddle that people can try and test.

Answer (score 0):

I'd search for the parent container, then grab the appropriate comment form:

```
$('.comment').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.news_box').find('.comment-form').dialog('open');
});
```

Given that `[.closest()][1]`:

1. Begins with the current element
2. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
3. The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set

You likely have some containing element above `div.news_box` that has a class of `.comment`. The above code (untested), should stop the `.closest()` match at `div.news_box` and then find the sole child element with class `.comment-form`, thus only opening a single dialog.

Comment: Your code doesn't work.. I enclosed the news_box in a div with a class of .comment and it does not work..

Comment: @Peanut: There's no need to wrap `div.news_box` in a `div.comment`, although I see in my answer where you may have construed that. I have reworded my answer for better clarity. If my answer still fails to work, try using `.parents()` instead of `.closest()`. If that still fails, please post some of the rendered HTML (after PHP renders it to the browser).